# C++ ,Single Inheritance, Garbage Value

Tags: c++, inheritance, garbage

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Alpha
{
    int a;
public:
    void get_a(int x)
    {
        a = x;
    }
    int hello()
    {
        return a;
    }
};
class Beta : public Alpha
{
    int b, c;
public:
    void get_b(int y)
    {
        b = y;
    }
    void add()
    {
        c = hello() + b;
        cout << c << endl; // displays garbage value
    }
};
int main()
{
    Alpha v1;
    Beta v2;
    v1.get_a(4);
    v2.get_b(3);
    v2.add();
    v2.disp();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of v2.disp() shows garbage value but when I initalise "a" as v2.get_a instead of v1.get_a , it shows the correct answer. New to C++ btw. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What is `disp`? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Also your naming is a little weird. You have functions named `get` that doesn't actually "get" anything but instead *set* values.

Comment: I'm sorry, disp was actually a function that was meant to print the value of the variable c. Forgot to add it since I was editing the code. But why garbage value is shown if I have already initialised the variable a. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different objects that are unrelated to each other. The object `v1` is unrelated to the object `v2`, they are separate and distinct objects. You initialize `Alpha::a` with `v1.get_a(4)`, that doesn't initialize `Beta::a`.

A solution to your problem is to use *one* object:

```
Beta v;
v.get_a(4);
v.get_b(3);
v.add();
v.disp();
```